# Razor anchor returning original view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on a search form, where the user press the Print button, then it should create a plain html page for printing:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Print()" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
    Print
</a>
```

And the Print() function (of course all the relevant data is passed):

```
$.get("@Url.Action("PrintData")", { ... ... ... });
```

This calls the appropriate controller action, which returns the correct data I am expecting with `return PartialView(data);`

The problem is, the new tab is not loading the PrintData.cshtml, instead it returns the original search screen.

What am I missing? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: If the current view is not the same as the original view, then you need to pass whatever values are necessary to the controller to generate the current view.

Comment: Show your print function.

Comment: What do you mean _the new tab is not loading the PrintData.cshtml_? You `$.get()` method does not have a success call back. And _"the new tab_ implies you want to render this in a new page, it which case do not use ajax (which is for staying on the same page)

Comment: The new tab is opened, but the search page's cshtml is loaded into it. Instead of `$.get()` what should I use?

Comment: I've tried `$("#Print").load` too, same result...

Comment: `$.get()` is an ajax call which means you stay on the same page (if you used `$.get(url, { ...", function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); }); you would see the view you returned. Use `location.href = url;` to redirect to your url.

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke, I am getting the data now, but the location is the problem...

Comment: If you want to redirect, then redirect. Don't use ajax (which is for staying on the same page)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96132/discussion-between-paxsentry-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' + '?target = "_blank"';
var data = "&projectId=" + id + "&date=" + date ...
window.open(url + data);
```